# How to add word to beginning of multiple files using powershell

Tags: windows, file, powershell, batch-file, renaming

Today I walked into my office and a couple guys were renaming hundreds and hundreds of files manually on the computer. I looked up ways to rename multiple files. I currently know how to replace a value with another value. Say for example `Dir | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace " ","_" }` which replaces all spaces in a file name to an underscore.

However, for my particular task, I need to add just a word in front of all of the file names, for example:

```
Johnhancock.pdf, AnitaMann.pdf, AmandaHugginkiss.pdf
```

into

```
(scores)Johnhancock.pdf, (scores)AnitaMann.pdf, (scores)AmandaHugginkiss.pdf
```

How would I would I do this? The parentheses are needed for this particular project.

Answer (score 2):

In that scriptblock you just have to generate the name that you want for each item. `$_` represents the current item. For your example it would be:

```
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName { "(scores)$($_.Name)" }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will process an entire directory tree with a batch file.  Remove the `echo` if what you see on the screen matches what you want.  Remove the `/r` to process only the current folder.

```
@echo off
for /r %%a in (*.txt) do echo ren "%%a" "(scores)%%~nxa"
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is the code as follows (I could not get the above to work):

```
Get-ChildItem *.pdf | rename-item -NewName { "(score)" + $_.Name }
```